# .Find not working in Word from Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to get information from a table in Word and pull it into Excel, since the number of tables is variable and I have no other way to reference the table I wanted to find the table directly after the text before it in the document. I've used the .Find method before but for some reason I can't get it to work this time and from everything I've read and used before, this should work:

```
Sub Process_NIM()
    Dim WordPullFile As Object
    Dim PullFolder As String
    Dim PullDate As Date
    Dim AppWord As Word.Application
    Dim wd As Word.Document
    Dim Table1 As Word.Table
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Text1 As Word.Range

    PullDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Now())
    PullFolder = "M:\Production Case Files\" & Format(PullDate, "YYYY") & _
        " Production Case Files\" & UCase(Format(PullDate, "MMM")) & _
        "\" & UCase(Format(PullDate, "MMM DD")) & "\"
    On Error GoTo OpenFileError
    Set WordPullFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With WordPullFile
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.clear
        .Filters.Add "DOC Files (*.doc)", "*.doc"
        .InitialFileName = PullFolder
        .Show
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WordPullFile.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        PullFolder = WordPullFile.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wd = AppWord.Documents.Open(PullFolder)
    wd.Application.Visible = True

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(2)

    If Text1.wd.Selection.Find.Execute(findtext:="Generator Outages for Today - Greater than 25MW") = True Then
        'do stuff
    End If

OpenFileError:
    MsgBox ("There was an error opening the word file. Try closing any other instances of word and re-run.")
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I use this from Word currently, but I can't get it to work from Excel:

```
If Text1.Find.Execute(findtext:="RC South Regional Review for") Then
    Text1.InsertAfter (" " & Format(FileDate, "MMMM DD, YYYY"))
End If
```

Comment: Text1.wd.Selection.Find Change to wd.Range.Find

Comment: That works in finding the text but it doesn't do what the code I have is intended to, that is, assign the location of the found text to Text1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the good news is, the text you say you use in word that doesn't work in excel, actually does work.  The issue is with the value you are trying to put in, I used your code and for a while I was stumped because it appeared to not be working, but when I substituted some plain text instead of your date, it worked fine, whihc told me the find was working.  It turns out it simply wasn't resolving Filedate as a date and so wasn't inserting anything.  Here is a version of your code, modified to work on my PC that does insert a date after the found string, did you mean to add Pulldate instead of Filedate as the variable to append maybe?

```
Sub Process_NIM()
    Dim WordPullFile As Object
    Dim PullFolder As String
    Dim PullDate As Date
    Dim AppWord As Word.Application
    Dim wd As Word.Document
    Dim Table1 As Word.Table
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Text1 As Word.Range

    PullDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Now())
    PullFolder = "D:\Users\Mark\Documents\"
    On Error GoTo OpenFileError
    Set WordPullFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With WordPullFile
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "DOC Files (*.doc)", "*.doc"
        .InitialFileName = PullFolder
        .Show
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WordPullFile.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        PullFolder = WordPullFile.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wd = AppWord.Documents.Open(PullFolder)
    wd.Application.Visible = True

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(2)

    Set Text1 = wd.Range
If Text1.Find.Execute(findtext:="RC South Regional Review for") Then
    Text1.InsertAfter (" " & Format(Date, "MMMM DD, YYYY"))
Else
    MsgBox "could not find text"
End If
wd.Save
wd.Close
AppWord.Quit
Set AppWord = Nothing

Exit Sub
OpenFileError:
    MsgBox ("There was an error opening the word file. Try closing any other instances of word and re-run.")
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: The second bit of code is from a different file but I was using that as a starting point for this file. I don't know how I didn't try setting Text1 = wd.range before but that apparently fixed it.